# How to add a new user in OpenLDAP via PHP?

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I want to add a new user in OpenLDAP and I write the following method to create a new user. When calling this method, I have to pass the following variables:

- `$ldapconn` : Returned by ldap_connect.
- `$username` : The username that I want to create.
- `$password` : The password for logging in the account.

---

```
public static function createNewUser($ldapconn, $username, $password) {
    if (!$ldapconn) { return false; }
    require_once("LDAPConfigurator.php");
    $r = ldap_bind($ldapconn, "cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com", "12345X");

    // Prepare data
    $info["cn"]="John Jones";
    $info["sn"]="Jones";
    $info["mail"]="jonj@example.com";
    $info["objectclass"]="person";

    // Add data to directory
    $r = ldap_add($ldapconn, "cn=John Jones,dc=test,dc=com", $info);

    return true;
}
```

The LDAP connection `$ldapconn` will be closed outside this method.

---

The prepared data is copied from [this document](http://titanic.fauser.edu/php/function.ldap-add.php.htm).

I expect it can show me a new child under "dc=test,dc=com" in phpLDAPadmin. But the final result is nothing appeared and shows me:

```
Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Object class violation in /var/www/html/test.php on line 23
```

I want to ask how to solve the problem (`Object class violation`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"inetOrgPerson" is the default object class for a person entry in OpenLDAP defined by inetorgperson.schema. So you need to do,

```
$info["objectclass"]="inetOrgPerson";
```

If you want to use a custom object class like "person" you need to extend inetOrgPerson in schema.

Comment: How to integrate the `$username` and `$password` to allow the user to login any of the openldap client linux machines?

Comment: @CasperLI  What you mean by " integrate the $username and $password" ?